# access salesforce community

Tags: community

If I created Salesforce community, can I and other people (with license company community) access to community like employee (not contact, from standard login), Is it possible to disable standard access to original salesforce (not community) and allow access only to community?

[image]

Comment: As long as they are Internal user you can't restrict them. You can disable their user and create new community user for them.

Answer (score 0):

Not as an internal user, you would have to specifically create community user accounts for them and disable the Salesforce accounts.

Depending on your use case for Salesforce this can be a good way to keep licencing costs controlled as the community licences are cheaper than full SFDC licences.